# Can I Detect a Date in ModelMetadata-CreateMetadata

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, metadata

I've used this override to detect enums and display a custom editor template for them. I'd like to  do the same with date/datetimes.

Is it possible to do it within the same block of code? I feel it should be easy, but can't quite work out how from the parameters it accepts.

```
public class MakeEnumsUseDefaultTemplate : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var mm = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);
        if (modelType.IsEnum && mm.TemplateHint == null)
        {
            mm.TemplateHint = "EnumAsSelect";
        }
        return mm;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just check `if (modelType == typeof(DateTime)) { ... }`?

Comment: Ah ok I can see now... thank you :)